# Loop not going inside when the value is same

Tags: c#

you can see that value is 74 but its not going inside the if  why? 
[image]

Comment: First - there is no such thing as `if loop`, second - do not post images, post code instead (also I can't see that image).

Comment: Because " 74" (with a blank) is not the same as "74" without the blank

Comment: You might want to use `Trim` on your strings before comparing.

Comment: Also, please edit your question: post the actual code in the question and properly format it.  Don't post a *picture* of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a space in `TEMP`.  `" 74"`.  The two values are not equal because the second one `TEMP2` is `"74"` without the space.

Try using `Trim` on your values to remove whitespace:

```
string temp = ids[i].Trim();
string temp2 = raditem.Value.ToString().Trim();
```

Also, always use [the .Equals overload for the `String` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_), as you can control the culture for the string comparison.  In this case it doesn't matter because they're numerals but it could matter if you want to compare to alphabetical strings where you want "A" to equal "a" and so forth.

Furthermore, if you are sure your array contains only numbers, I could recommend converting the values to numbers before comparing them.

```
// one way to validate is wrap this in a try-catch and handle input format error.
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(ids[i].Trim());
```

That way if you have a case where there *aren't* numbers, you could validate and complain to the user or whatever you want.